# How to find missing co-ordinate on parallelogram

Tags: geometry

ABCD is a parallelogram. A, B and C equal (1,1), (4, 3) and (-1, 4) respectively.

I have worked out the length of AB and AC to be the root of 13, and ABC is a right-angled triangle as I was asked to prove that (by showing AB and AC are equal).  The gradient of AB = 2/3.

I'm simply stuck on finding co-ordinate D.  The topic we are doing in class is co-ordinate geometry, so I know about finding the length and straight line equations.

I'd appreciate help or direction in what to do.

Comment: Could you clarify one thing for me, please? Is $D$ supposed to make a side with $A$ or with $B$?

Answer (score 1):

Use the fact that the midpoint of the line segment $AC$ is also the midpoint of the line segment $BD$.

Let $D(x,y)$. Then, you have
$$\frac{1+(-1)}{2}=\frac{4+x}{2}\quad\text{and}\quad \frac{1+4}{2}=\frac{3+y}{2}.$$

Comment: I just realized that we're talking about the two possibilities for $D$, but from the question it isn't clear which should be preferred...

Comment: @A.P.: But for the latter case, its name should be either "ABDC" or "ACDB", shouldn't it? The question says "ABCD is a parallelogram".

Comment: That depends on the convention by which you label the vertices, which I don't think is universally fixed. Since the OP is talking about the lengths of $AB$ and $AC$ I thought that those are supposed to be sides.

Comment: @A.P.: Sorry, but I don't get what you mean. The question says "A, B and C equal (1,1), (4, 3) and (-1, 4) **respectively**". My understanding is that it says that we have $A(1,1),B(4,3),C(-1,4)$.

Comment: Yes that is correct mathlove, but how are the midpoints equal if they are 2 separate lines?

Comment: @TiernanWatson: Because "Diagonals of a parallelogram bisect each other" is a property of a parallelogram. See [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelogram#Properties).

Comment: @mathlove Of course. With those vertices fixed you can have two parallelograms. In one case the vertices are labelled counter-clockwise, in the other case they are labelled "linearly", i.e. $ABDC$ counter-clockwise.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** You should be able to draw your parallelogram even if you don't know the coordinates of $D$, at least approximately.

Assuming that you are labelling the parallelogram's vertices counter-clockwise (so that $D$ has negative abscissa), what can you tell about the projection of the side $DA$ on the $y$ axis compared with the projection of the side $AB$? What about the projection of the side $DA$ on the $x$ axis compared with the projection of the side $BC$?

---

For example, write $x(P)$ for the $x$ coordinate of a point $P$. Note that you can get to $D$ by "moving" from $A$ along the side $AD$, which you know must be congruent to $BC$. Thus
$$
x(D) = x(A) + x(C) - x(B) = -x(B) = -4.
$$
You can reason similarly about $y(D)$.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming $ ABDC $ anti-clockwise, as parallel lines must have equal $x,y$ differences,
$$ x +1 = 4-1, y-4=3-1$$

or

$$ x= 2, y=6$$

$D$ makes side with $B$ for given order; $A$ and $D$ are diagonally opposite. A rough sketch settles the matter with vertex placement order.